# How to make multi line to single line based on space character in PHP?

Tags: php, string

Example file:

```
Aiken, L. S., & West, S. G. (1991). Multiple Regression: Testing and Interpreting
      interactions. Sage Publications.
Bai, X., Yao, W., & Boyer, J. E. (2012). Robust ﬁtting of mixture regression
      models. Computational Statistics & Data Analysis, 56 (7), 2347-2359.
Bartolucci, F., & Scaccia, L. (2005). The use of mixtures for dealing with
      non-normal regression errors. Computational Statistics & Data Analysis,
      48 (4), 821-834.
```

If I do `file("example")`,Its considering  like below:

```
1st line- Aiken, L. S., & West, S. G. (1991). Multiple Regression: Testing and Interpreting
          2nd line- interactions. Sage Publications
```

but it should be in a single line. So, I need to make that two lines as single line based on the space which second line have.As such I need all the reference list to be structured.

If I do like this,

```
$data = str_replace("\r\n", "", $data);
```

then all the lines will become 
as single line. I want each reference to be single line.

I tried,

```
$f=file("example")
for($i=0;$i<count($f);$i++){
$f[$i] = str_replace("\r\n", "", $f[$i]);
????
//should replace the new line strings to single line til it finds no space in the
 //new line string so that i can structure second reference in a second line and so
 //on.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `$data = str_replace("\r\n      ", " ", $data);` or `$data = str_replace("\n      ", " ", $data);` should take care of it. That is, if that's actually consistently six (6) spaces. (as long as it's consistent, you can correct my spacing if I got it wrong.)

EDIT:
Try this:

```
$f=file_get_contents("example");
$f=str_replace("\n      ", " ", $f);
$f=explode("\n",$f);
...
```

Comment: How to take two lines as single data to parse into `str_replace("\r\n      ", " ", $data)`.For example,In first reference two lines is a data to replace a new line charac.So, If I use `file()` it will take first line as single data second line as second data therefore how to replace new line charac between these two lines